# How to make a cell value a variable for an Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Im totally new to making macros in Excel!

Im trying to use the value from one cell as an input for my Array, but im getting a "subscript out of range" issue.

```
Sub Macro1()

MyValue = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(MyValue)).Select

End Sub
```

The value at A1=1,2,4 which correspond to the available sheets. Putting the value in directly works like a charm by the way.

Thanks

Comment: is `MyValue` your array ?

Comment: The value of MyValue is "1,2,4" should be the array

Comment: so you want your array to be `MyValue (0) = 1` , `MyValue (1) = 2` and `MyValue (2) = 4` ? on which of these you want to select your Worksheet ? od you want to loop thourgh all of them ?

Comment: I have like 10 sheets in my workbook and i want the value in A1 to determine which sheets need to be active (at the same time). So in this example the sheets 1,2, and 4 need to be active. After I get this to work I can use the ActiveSheet.printout function

Comment: Now we are geting somewhere... Wait. I will see what I can do.

Comment: FYI `Range` is a two dimensional array, `Array()` in its simplest form is one dimensional, therefore the error `subscript out of range`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your post, try the code below and let me know if that's what you meant.

Adding the optional argument to `False` allows selection extended to mulitple sheets.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim MyValue
Dim i As Integer

MyValue = Split(ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), ",")

For i = 0 To UBound(MyValue)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CInt(MyValue(i))).Select (False)    
Next i     

End Sub
```

Comment: The macro is running without an error, so that good! But only Sheet 4 is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
Sub print_sheets()
    MyValue = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value

    MyArr = Split(MyValue, ",")

    For Each Value In MyArr


        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CInt(Value)).Activate
        ' Change the directory below
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            "C:\Users\<<<USER>>>>\Documents\" & Value & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
            True


    Next Value


End Sub
```

This reads A1 and splits it. Activates the sheets and prints the on paper.
I can't make them print on pdf unless I know what to call the sheets.
EDIT: I made them save with the sheetnumber as the name of the file.

[image]

Comment: If I use the Split function, I get an error of types mismatch!

Comment: Don't know if it was my mistake here.. I see that I left the code with range("I1") and not A1. But other that that it should work unless there is something else that you are not telling us. Edited the code to A1. If that was the problem.

Comment: this is my code now, maybe im missing something. Like i said im totally new to this!

Comment: Sub Macro1()

MyValue = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value

MyArr = Split(MyValue, ",")
  
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(MyArr)).Select

End Sub

Comment: What is the thisworkbook.sheets... line? What is that line supposed to do?

Comment: It should select the sheets, with the values given from MyArr, within the active workbook. So in this case sheets 1,2 and 4. So after that I can use the activeSheets.printout function

Comment: What?? I have no clue what you are actually trying to do. Step by step now. What do you want to happen, use words and not code, because frankly you can't code. 1. Grab value from A1? 2. Split the value to an array? 3. now what??

Comment: yeah I can't code that well. So in words. 1. Grab the value from A1 2. Use those values (in this example 1,2,4) to activate the Sheets 1, 2, and 4 3. Print those sheets to pdf

Comment: I tested it but it's only selecting sheet 4. I also tested the answer of Shai Rado and it work perfectly for me. Thank you for your effort though, i really appreciate it!!!

Comment: @Gerald_LD It selects one at the time and saves them to pdf. Look in the directory and you will find three files. One pdf per sheet. His code does not even save them as pdf??? How can you say that works perfect?

Comment: You are right about the not printing part, but i explained that in the comments. The original code was about activating the sheets and he did that. I tested the updated code you posted and it indeed creates multiple single pdfs. So i think that's the difference between the 2 codes. Yours select the sheets and function it as single pages and Shai Allows me to add multiple active sheets to a single pdf. For me that's more convenient. I can't mark two appearently, for other people that need exactly that. Thank you!